# Evaluate a function with different KIND

Tags: fortran, polymorphism

Consider a function that **adds** two number (e.g. integer, Real). I have to write the same function with the same code many times but with different precision and then create an interface.

Can somebody give me an example how to do the same with Fortran **select type**.

Comment: Have you searched this site? There are certainly examples of select type here. I think you should first show us an example what you exactly mean.

Answer (score 0):

No... But it is possible in a module

All the math for scalars and doubles already does exactly what you want, so the procedures would be mostly for functions or subroutines that are doing significantly more bespoke work than a simple add or multiply.

Do you have any starting example?

Is this for a course you are taking?
If it is for a course then search for "module procedure interface".